# Create a many-to-many relationship in a model to itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make a proper `join` table that only deals with one model, I plan on setting up CRUD pages for this table that I plan on using later so I believe it can't be part of the original model.

```cs
public class Person
{
  [Key]
  public int PersonID { get; set;}

  public string Firstname { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set;}
  public string Birthday { get; set;}
}
```

Now I would like to keep track, of people, their best friends and what their best friends birthdays are.

```cs
public class Friends
{
  [Key]
  public int FriendshipID {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Person")]
  public Person SelectedPerson {get; set;}
  public int SelectedPersonID {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Person")]
  public Person Friend {get; set;}
  public int FriendID {get; set;}
}
```

There are some issues with this, one I don't completely know how `[ForeignKey("xxxx")]` works but this seems to cause an error. It's possible for a person to have multiple best friends so I would have to have many entries in the friends table where the `SelectedPerson` would be the same in order to get all of their best friends, I feel like if there was a good way to get a list of their friends instead of just a singular friend at a time that would have an advantage but that seems to cause some sort of cascade delete error?

I know there are questions similar to this one on stackoverflow, but I could not find any where it was joining back to the same table, I currently have the ForeignKeys commented out because EF couldn't handle foreignkeys of the same name.

Any help/suggestions is very much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `InverseProperty` in parent class to define multiple relations

and **don't** use a duplicate name for `ForeignKey`

```cs
public class Person
{
  [Key]
  public int PersonID { get; set;}

  public string Firstname { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set;}
  public string Birthday { get; set;}

  [InverseProperty("SelectedPerson")]
  public ICollection<Friends> SelectedPerson { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Friend")]
  public ICollection<Friends> SelectedFriends { get; set; }
}
```

then change the `Friends` class to this

```cs
public class Friends
{
  [Key]
  public int FriendshipID {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("SelectedPersonID")]
  public Person SelectedPerson {get; set;}
  public int SelectedPersonID {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("FriendID")]
  public Person Friend {get; set;}
  public int FriendID {get; set;}
}
```